# How to set javascript variable to flask template variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I want to set the javascript variable value to flask template variable in javascript. What I am trying is

```
$(document).on("click", ".prepopulate", function () {
 var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
 alert(myBookId); // The value is showing proper
 {% set tempVar = 'myBookId' %}
 alert ({{tempVar}}) 
});
```

But it's giving an error instead (UndefinedError: 'list object' has no attribute 'myBookId'). What is the way to set the template variable in javascript using javascript variable?

Comment: What error is giving?

Comment: $(document).on("click", ".prepopulate", function () { var myBookId = $(this).data('id');  alert(myBookId); // The value is showing proper
 {% set tempVar = 'myBookId' %}
 alert ("==="+{{tempVar}})
}); The alerts gives proper value. But when I am accessing it in the html code like <input type="text" class="form-control" width="20" name="routername" id="routername" placeholder="Router Name *" required data-validation-required-message="Enter Router Name" value="{{item[tempVar].name}}"><br/></td> ...     UndefinedError: 'list object' has no attribute 'myBookId'

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `set` like this:

```
%SET{"tempVar" value="myBookId"}%
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Looks like doesn't work with this. Can you please elaborate more. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this because jinja runs before the page loads and on the server side but the javascript code is executed when the page is loading and on the client side (browser) so your `myBookId` variable doesn't exist for jinja (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123618/pass-javascript-variables-into-my-macro-in-jinja2) answer for more info). A way to achieve what you want is to use `ajax`. See [here](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/flask-and-jquery-ajax) an example.

Comment: OK. In the template I have dropdown. Based on the dropdown index I want to use the flask template list like  e.g. If I select first value from dropdown it should select something like {{list[1]}} for second {{list[2]}}. But the value of index needs to be passed runtime. Please guide how I can do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your rendered HTML you will see

```
alert (myBookId)
```

Unless you define a variable called `myBookId`, this is not valid JavaScript. You need to wrap the string value in quotes.

```
alert('{{ myBookId }}')
```

An even better way to do this is to let Jinja decide for you if quotes are needed.

```
alert({{ myBookId|tojson|safe }})
```

This will wrap string values in strings, leave integers alone, and use JavaScript booleans.